# Как правильно давать имена структурным элементам в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Каждый раз, когда даю имя, делаю это как-то по-разному. Хотелось бы делать как это принято в сообществе...

- Переменные,
- Методы,
- Методы в контроллере,
- Имена blade шаблонов,
- таблицы БД,
- модели,
- сервисы,
- пермишены для ролей
- и т.д.

Приведу пару примеров... Как правильно дать имя контроллеру, который просто отображает страницу? нужно начинать с get/show/page/... ? Как назвать имя blade-шаблона? admin_panel или adminPanel? Недавно давал названия пермишенам. Получилось примерно так GET_ALL_OWNER_REPORT_STATISTIC. Так обычно именуют константы. Понимаю, что все условно. Но также знаю, что есть какие-то неписанные правила как это делать лучше, чтобы мой код был читаем другими разработчиками. Не могу найти подходящую информацию на форумах. Подскажите где почитать. Желательно применительно к ларавелю, но наверное это необязательно.

Comment: Как классно, когда разработчик думает о других разработчиках, которые возможно будут работать с его кодом.

Answer (score 3):

Вот [тут](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md) есть очень много хороших практик. [Вот](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) тема связанная с именованием.

Все на русском!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]